# how to store plain text as well as image inside edittext in android

Tags: android

I have a scenario in my app where I am creating a post and saving to DB. **Post can contain plain text as well as image or link in EditText box.**

I am not sure how to store data from EditText which has both Image and text, so that while showing the post to user It renders it correctly.

To store Image and text I am using SpannableString

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc\n");
Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editT.setText(ss);
```

If i directly try to store data from editText value then i am getting exception.
Please help me.

Comment: You are going to need to convert the `SpannableString` into some other format that can be persisted, such as XHTML. In particular, you will need to convert the `ImageSpan` into something where you record what drawable you are using for that span. While I have [a library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit) that helps with converting `SpannableString` to and from XHTML, I do not have `ImageSpan` support at this time.

Comment: you can use this [library](https://github.com/sufficientlysecure/html-textview) which can load `HTML` and converts it into `Spannable`

Comment: @CommonsWare can you give any sample code on how to use RichEdit  for storing plain text and Image both for my requirement.